# Why do you need to create these json read/write when in java you didn't have to?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

Please correct me if I am wrong, but when using Java with say Spring MVC you didn't have to create these extra classes to map your Java class to JSON and JSON to class.

Why do you have to do this in Play with Scala?  Is it something to do with Scala?

```
case class Location(lat: Double, long: Double)

implicit val locationWrites: Writes[Location] = (
  (JsPath \ "lat").write[Double] and
  (JsPath \ "long").write[Double]
)(unlift(Location.unapply))


implicit val locationReads: Reads[Location] = (
  (JsPath \ "lat").read[Double] and
  (JsPath \ "long").read[Double]
)(Location.apply _)
```

Comment: In your case you can just use this: `implicit val locationWrites = Json.writes[Location]` and `implicit val locationReads = Json.reads[Location]`

Comment: @serejja yes but why do you have to do that in scala but not in java?

Comment: "\" symbol cannot be resolved, do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why you have to do it in Play is a **framework design choice**, and it is a very good one.

In Play, the mechanism relies on **Scala implicits**, which are a very powerful feature leveraged to make the mechanism highly **pluggable** , in the sense that at the moment you call:

```
Json.toJson(Location(4.5, 5.3))
```

The compiler will look for an **implicit** in scope matching the required type. The **Scala language specification** describes the algorithm to resolve implicits, and such algorithm is designed in a way that you can "**import**" an implicit in a limited scope. Thanks to this feature, in different part of your program you can make visible a different implementation of your Reads / Writes or any typeclass .

```
object MyImplicits {

    object ImplicitJson1{
        implicit val write:Write[Location] = "write to json all fields"
    }

    object ImplicitJson2{
        implicit val write:Write[Location] = "skip field a"
    }
}

object MyBusinessCode{

    def f1(location:Location){
        import MyImplicits.ImplicitJson1._
        Json.toJson(location)
    }
    def f2(location:Location){
        import MyImplicits.ImplicitJson2._
        Json.toJson(location)
    }

    def dynamicChoice(location:Location){
        implicit val write = {
            if(location.isEurope)           
                MyImplicits.ImplicitJson1.write
            else
                MyImplicits.ImplicitJson2.write
        }
        Json.toJson(location)
    }

}
```

Instead, in Spring this is typically done through introspection and reflection. You might need to use annotations to help Spring determining how to build your Json from your data model. The consequence is that you cannot change the way it is done, and therefore you have less flexibility.

Since you might not need more flexibility, many Scala libraries/framework provides you functions to generate default implementation of the typeclass you need. That extra line of code

```
implicit val fmt = Json.format[Location]
```

is the price that you have to pay because Play json serialization relies on implicit.

Comment: Although this is a good answer, you could perhaps elaborate a bit more that Play's approach relies more on *type safety*. If your Play JSON deserializer compiles *you know it will work* during runtime. The compiler will check whether your deserialization code results in the proper classes with the appropriate fields. With Spring, this check happens *when your application is running* so you'll have to keep your fingers crossed you don't get runtime exceptions. Since these exceptions cannot happen with Play's solution, I think that solution is far better.

Comment: Let me disagree: the compiler doesn't check whether your serialization code results in the proper classes with the appropriate fields, it only checks the signatures. Your code is still able to fail at runtime, exactly as Spring framework does. The benefit of the way JSON serialization is implemented in Play is not type safety but pluggability / configurability .

Comment: "the compiler doesn't check whether your serialization code results in the proper classes with the appropriate fields". But it does? The compiler specifically checks (or generates by macro) the appropriate code for binding strings to case class fields. Jackson doesn't do that. There is far less room for error with Play. It also does not let you use deserialized JSON without unwrapping a resulting `Either` or `Option`, so that means you "have to" consider malformed JSON. Play's way eliminates mismatches between the schemas of your JSON and case classes much more effectively at compile time.

Comment: I agree on everything you said, but I don't think is has something to do with type safety. The only part where I see specifically the type system playing a role is in the implicit resolution...

Comment: The "type safety" part is where you cannot address a field in the case class which *does not exist* when deserializing JSON. This is entirely possible with a reflection based solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to:

```
case class Location(lat: Double, long: Double)

object Location {

  implicit val fmt = Json.format[Location]

}

Json.toJson(Location(4.5, 5.3)) // returns JsValue
```

The hand-written reads/writes/formats are useful when your JSON structure doesn't match your object definition.

Comment: i.e. in `spray-json` there are implemented transformations for basic/primitive types to json. But sometimes you need to perform some advanced `marshalling`/`unmarshalling` that needs to be implemented.

Comment: Ok but you still had to write the Json.format[Type].

Comment: My question was why do you even have to create that implicit when in Java you don't have to?  Is it something to do with the Scala language?

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't mentioned which JSON/Spring library integration you meant, I am taking example of JSON via Jackson / Spring integration. I believe it takes advantage of Java Beans field naming convention. This would involve reflection and that happens at run-time.

However, Play's Scala Json library provides compile time safety of all the type in your JSON data. Also it gives you a nice functional syntax `map`, `flatMap`, `orElse` etc. This is a huge advantage.

See this question for more:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/228193/json-library-jackson-or-play-framework

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it's possible to write function with default implicit parameter like

```
def toJson[T](x: T)(implicit fmt: Reads[T] = Json.format[T]) = Json.toJson(x)(fmt)
```

But in case of Play Json it will not work because Json.format[T] is a macro and it cannot resolve generic-type symbol T. It can resolve only symbols which directly refers to case classes or any with unapply (see [sources](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsMacroImpl.scala))

On the other hand, it seems to be possible to write a macro which generates same function as i described but instead of Apply( Json.format[T]) uses AST from [JsMacroImpl.macroImpl](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsMacroImpl.scala)(c, "format", ...).

Anyway, it's not a language restriction - it's just not implemented in given library.